# What story has the narrator include the word 'data' in his thoughts to get the computer to answer?

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

I read this in the 1970's. The story works like this:

> "I was talking to Smith about the strike data 12th March to 14th April
>   and the role of data John Tobin in the uprising that followed."

The whole narration has the word '*data*' interspersed and you come to realise that the narrator is having their memory/recall injected with facts supplied by the computer throughout. I think this is a prescient example of folk Googling answers to questions during conversations.

Comment: How closely does the string of text (about the strike) mirror what was *actually* in the story?

Comment: Only that it is first person. I cannot remember any of the detail and made this up.